# while read two lines as one string variable

Tags: string, bash, shell, awk, while-loop

Here is what i am trying to do:
I have an out of a following command:

```
result=`awk /^#.*/{print;getline;print} file1.txt
echo "$result"
```

Output is:

```
#first comment
first line
#second comment
second line
#third comment
third line.
```

if i have to put $result into while loop and capture two lines as one string variable and print it, how can i do it?

Example:

```
echo "$result" | while read m
do
echo "Value of m is: $m"
done
```

Output is:

```
Value of m is:#first comment
Value of m is:first line
Value of m is:#second comment
Value of m is:second line
Value of m is:#third comment
Value of m is:third line.
```

But the Expected output is:

```
Value of m is:
#first comment
first line
Value of m is:
#second comment
second line
Value of m is:
#third comment
third line.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while read -r first; read -r second
do
    printf '%s\n' 'Value of m is:' "$first" "$second"
done
```

Or if you need the lines in the variable:

```
while read -r first; read -r second
do
    m="$first"$'\n'"$second"
    echo 'Value of m is:'
    echo "$m"
done
```

Comment: This works, but I'd use command-grouping to make what's going on just a little bit clearer, e.g. `while { read -r first; read -r second; } do`.

Comment: This works fantastic, thanks for the suggestion CodeGnome I used the same.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `awk`. In each odd line read next one and join them between a newline character.

```
awk '
    FNR % 2 != 0 { 
        getline line; 
        result = $0 "\n" line; 
        print "Value:\n" result; 
    }
' infile
```

Assuming content of `infile` is:

```
#first comment
first line
#second comment
second line
#third comment
third line.
```

Running previous `awk` command output will be:

Value:

```
Value:
#first comment
first line
Value:
#second comment
second line
Value:
#third comment
third line.
```